# Is the way to make this union of postgres queries more efficient is to use a materialized view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So right now, I have the following postgres query in a Rails 5.0 application - The first query basically sums viewership and groups by domestic and international stations (radio_category) as well as FM and AM (radio_type).  The second query totals viewership across all domestic and international stations and groups by FM/AM.

To make it more efficient, is it better to try and write a put a raw select statement to pull only the numbers that will eventually need to be summed in a materialized view, and then write a SUM()/GROUP_BY statement to pull from the view?

Or is there some clever use of SUM() I can do that only lets me `select *` the raw numbers once?

Let's say I have at least 1 million rows of data.

```
   SELECT numbers.snapshot_id,
      count(*) AS radio_count,
      sum(numbers.view_count) AS view_count,
      radios.category AS radio_category,
      radios.type AS radio_type,
      CASE
        WHEN radios.type = 'AM' THEN 0
        WHEN radios.type = 'FM' THEN 1
      END as radio_enum_type
     FROM (numbers
       JOIN radios ON ((radios.id = numbers.radio_id)))
    GROUP BY numbers.snapshot_id, radios.category, radios.type
  UNION
   SELECT numbers.snapshot_id,
      count(*) AS radio_count,
      sum(numbers.view_count) AS view_count,
      3 AS radio_category,
      radios.type AS radio_type,
      CASE
        WHEN radios.type = 'AM' THEN 0
        WHEN radios.type = 'FM' THEN 1
      END as radio_enum_type
     FROM (numbers
       JOIN radios ON ((radios.id = numbers.radio_id)))
    GROUP BY numbers.snapshot_id, 3::integer, radios.type
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a row without UNION. So not sure if this is better but you could precalculate the aggregation and then make the UNION from it. However, maybe your query gets optimized by Postgres and might be the same...

```
WITH aggregated_numbers AS (
  SELECT numbers.snapshot_id,
  count(*) AS radio_count,
  sum(numbers.view_count) AS view_count,
  radios.category AS radio_category,
  radios.type AS radio_type,
  CASE
    WHEN radios.type = 'AM' THEN 0
    WHEN radios.type = 'FM' THEN 1
  END as radio_enum_type
 FROM (numbers
   JOIN radios ON ((radios.id = numbers.radio_id)))
 GROUP BY numbers.snapshot_id, radios.category, radios.type)
 SELECT * FROM aggregated_numbers 
 UNION
 SELECT 
   snapshot_id,
   sum(radio_count) as radio_count,
   view_count,
   3 as radio_category,
   radio_type,
   radio_enum_type
 FROM aggregated_numbers
```

Comment: Thanks, it's all simply to display the data in HTML, so I thought it seemed inefficient to have to run a select query twice with a different `group by` just to get the aggregate totals I wanted.